# create table dom width jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this *long* code about a table width some various content.
It is also available at http://jsfiddle.net/Rtv7u/8/

I would like to rewrite it in jquery in the hope that it will work nice in IE and will be shorter and clearer.

I don't ask you to "translate" the full code, but give instructions or reference how to do that. (Or example about the beginning)

Thanks.

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
    table.width  = 625;
    table.className="feltoltesek_tabla_szegely";
    var tr1 = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        td1.width = 20; 
        td1.align="center";
        td1.height = 32;
        td1.rowSpan=3;
            var chb = document.createElement('input');
            chb.type="checkbox";
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        td2.rowSpan = 3;
        td2.width = 20; 
        td2.align="center";
            var kuka = document.createElement('div');
            kuka.className = "spr_kuka";
        var td3 = document.createElement('td');
        td3.rowSpan = 3;
        td3.width =  20; 
        td3.align="center";
            var dupl = document.createElement('div');
            dupl.className = "spr_dupl";
        var td4 = document.createElement('td');
        td4.rowSpan = 3;
        td4.width = 135;
        td4.align = "center";
        $('<img/>').attr('src',"http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png")
            .css({display:'none',width:76})
            .appendTo(td4)
            .load(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(1000); });
        var td5 = document.createElement('td');
            td5.innerHTML = "file.name";
        var td6 = document.createElement('td');
        td6.width = 100;
            var meret= document.createElement('select');
            meret.className = "sel_sm";
        var td7 = document.createElement('td');
        td7.width = 80;
            var db = document.createElement('input');
            db.className = "box_sm";
            db.size=3;
            db.type="text";
            var db_span = document.createElement('span');
            db_span.innerHTML = "&nbsp;*";
    var tr2 = document.createElement('tr');
        tr2.height = 21;
        var tdu1 = document.createElement('td');
        var tdu2 = document.createElement('td');
        var tdu3 = document.createElement('td');
        var tdu4 = document.createElement('td');
        var tdu5 = document.createElement('td');
        var tdu6 = document.createElement('td');
        var tdu7 = document.createElement('td');
        var tdu8 = document.createElement('td');            
        var keparany = document.createElement('td');
        keparany.colSpan=3;
        keparany.innerHTML = "row2";
        var felbontas = document.createElement('td');
        felbontas.colSpan=3;
        felbontas.innerHTML = "row3";
    var tr3 = document.createElement('tr');
        tr3.height = 21;
    td1.appendChild(chb);
    td2.appendChild(kuka);
    td3.appendChild(dupl);
    td6.appendChild(meret);
    td7.appendChild(db);        
    td7.appendChild(db_span);    
    tr1.appendChild(td1);
    tr1.appendChild(td2);
    tr1.appendChild(td3);
    tr1.appendChild(td4);
    tr1.appendChild(td5);
    tr1.appendChild(td6);
    tr1.appendChild(td7);
    tr2.appendChild(keparany);
    tr3.appendChild(felbontas);
    table.appendChild(tr1);
    table.appendChild(tr2);
    table.appendChild(tr3);
    var e2 = document.getElementById('id');
    e2.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jquery, you can create elements using their HTML code. For example :

```
jQuery("<p>hello <span style='color:green'>world !</span>");
```

So, you can simply do that :

http://jsfiddle.net/Rtv7u/9/

Comment: thats nice! but what if there is some special content in the code:
$('<img/>').attr('src',"http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png")
            .css({display:'none',width:76})
            .appendTo(td4)
            .load(function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(1000); });

Comment: You are right. Can I ask why do you need to create that table in javascript ? That will help me to understand :)

Comment: on my page people can upload more pictures, and that files are listed immediately (in a table) and the table cells turn into pictures and to its data as the upload finished

Comment: So I suggest you to use an hidden table that you can easily clone, like here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Rtv7u/14/ . Is that the idea of what you want ?

Comment: I dont clone them because the rows content are different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the tag where you want to put the code in and then you just need to give a html string in the function html

```
$("#id").html('<table width="625" class="feltoltesek_tabla_szegely"><tr><td width="20" align="center" height="32" rowspan="3"><input type="checkbox"></td><td rowspan="3" width="20" align="center"><div class="spr_kuka"></div></td><td rowspan="3" width="20" align="center"><div class="spr_dupl"></div></td><td rowspan="3" width="135" align="center"><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="width: 76px; "></td><td>file.name</td><td width="100"><select class="sel_sm"></select></td><td width="80"><input class="box_sm" size="3" type="text"><span>&nbsp;*</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">row2</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3">row3</td></tr></table>');
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rtv7u/16/
API of .html() here: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different techniques you can use.  You can, as you are doing here, add each element one by one and building up a table that then gets added to the DOM.  You an also construct the entire table as a string of HTML and add that all at once.  It's hard to imagine why you'd need to do the latter, since you could just as easily construct the table manually in the response as construct it as a string, but that would be a reasonable replacement for exactly this code.

```
 var tbl = '<table style="width: 625;" class="foo"><tr><td rowspan="3" style="width: 20; ...';
 $(tbl).appendTo('#id');
```

or

```
var $row1 = $('<tr></tr>').append('<td rowspan="3" style="width: 20;...">content</td>')
                          .append( ... more columns );

$('<table></table>').css({ width: 625 }).addClass('foo')
                    .append($row1)
                    .append($row2)
                    .appendTo('#id');
```